# Rails fields_for not rendering on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am trying to implement a form that has associated videos when I create a new tutorial. The issue is that my form is not rendering whenever I visit the page. Could anyone help, please?

This is myapp/views/admin/tutorials/new.html.erb

```
<h2>New Tutorial</h2>
<%= form_for [:admin, @tutorial] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: "block col-4 field" %>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description, class: "block col-4 field"  %>
  <%= f.label :thumbnail %>
  <%= f.text_field :thumbnail, class: "block col-4 field"  %>

  <h3>Videos</h3>

  <%= f.fields_for :videos do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :youtube_url %>
    <%= builder.text_field :youtube_url, class: "block col-4 field" %>
    <%= builder.label :video_id %>
    <%= builder.text_field :video_id, class: "block col-4 field" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "mt2 btn btn-primary mb1 bg-teal"  %>
<% end %>
```

This is my Video model

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_videos
  has_many :users, through: :user_videos
  belongs_to :tutorial

  validates_presence_of :position 
end
```

And my Tutorial model

```
class Tutorial < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :videos, ->  { order(position: :ASC) }, dependent: :destroy
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags, :tag_list
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :videos

  scope :without_classroom, -> { where(classroom: false) }
end
```

My controller:

```
 class Admin::TutorialsController < Admin::BaseController

  def new
    @tutorial = Tutorial.new
  end

  def create
    @tutorial = Tutorial.new(tutorial_params)
    if @tutorial.save
      flash[:success] = "Successfully created tutorial!"
      redirect_to tutorial_path(@tutorial)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @tutorial = Tutorial.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    tutorial = Tutorial.find(params[:id])
    if tutorial.update(tutorial_params)
      flash[:success] = "#{tutorial.title} tagged!"
    end
    redirect_to edit_admin_tutorial_path(tutorial)
  end

  private
  def tutorial_params
    params.require(:tutorial).permit(:tag_list, :title, :description, :thumbnail)
  end
end
```

Comment: What is rendering? Anything? What does your controller look like? Any errors?

Comment: My initial form_for is rendering, it's just that my fields_for form for associated videos is not rendering. There are no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason nothing's rendered is that the `videos` association is empty. For example if you add `@tutorial.videos.build` in the `new` controller action, then you will get one set of the fields, and if you have multiple videos in the association (whether persisted or not) you would get one set of the fields per video.